# Matlab Grayscale Normalization

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new to matlab and to image processing, and I am having some issues normalizing but I am not sure why.

In my code I store the image as a black and white image in lim3, then:

```
minvalue = min(min(min(lim3)));
maxvalue = max(max(max(lim3)));
normimg = (lim3-minvalue)*255/(maxvalue-minvalue);
```

Unfortunately, this gives a new image that is exactly the same as lim3 at all, but I am not sure why.  Ideally, I don't want to use the histeq function, so if someone could explain how to fix this code to get it to work, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not trying to save changes to lim3, I'm hoping to make a new image stored in norming, the same dimensions as lim3

Comment: what data type is your image `lim3`? is it double or `uint8`?

Comment: can you give part of data in lim3 ?  it it because the value in lim3 is too close to each other

Comment: the values are doubles and they are all between zero and one.  I just tried replacing the 255 with 1, but the results were the same.

Comment: Use this as an example - `im = imread('http://digital.cs.usu.edu/~xqi/Teaching/REU05/Labs/Food.jpg'),lim3 = im2double(im)` and then use your code. To show results use `uint8()`. Results seem good enough if you compare im and the output. So, check your minvalue and maxvalue for the input image you are using, most probably they are close to 0 and 1 respectively which could be salt and pepper kind of noise too.

Comment: what are your values for `minvalue` and `maxvalue`? Also `min(min(min(lim3)))` can be written as `min(lim3(:))`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the image is exactly the same? The same actual numbers? Or looks the same when you view it? Because it's possible that whatever tool you're using to view the image is smart enough to know if your image has values ranging 0-1 or 0-255 and scales them accordingly

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the (:).  And after the images were generated, I checked if they were equal, which they were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the people above in the comments have raised very good points, but if you want a `tl;dr` answer, here are the most important points:

1. If your minimum and maximum values are `0` and `255` respectively **for all colour channels**, this means that the minimum and maximum colour values are black and white respectively.  This is the same situation if your image was a single channel image / grayscale.  As such, if you try and normalize your output image, it will look the same as you would be multiplying and dividing by the same scale.   However, just as a minor note, your above code will work if your image is **grayscale**.  I would also get rid of the superfluous nested `min`/`max` calls.
2. You need to make sure that your image is cast to `double` before you do this scaling as you will most likely generate floating point numbers.  Should your scale be `< 1`, this will inadvertently be truncated to 0.  In general, you will lose precision when you're trying to normalize the intensities as the type of the image is most likely `uint8`.  You also need to remember to cast back to `uint8` when you're done, as that is what the original type of the image was before you cast.  You can do this casting, or you can use `im2double` as this essentially does what you want under the hood, but normalizes the image's intensities to the range of `[0,1]`.

---

As such, if you really really really really... really... want to use your code above, you'd have to do something like this:

```
lim3 = double(lim3); %// Cast to double
minvalue = min(lim3(:)); %// Note the change here
maxvalue = max(lim3(:)); %// Got rid of superfluous nested min/max calls
normimg = uint8((lim3-minvalue)*255/(maxvalue-minvalue)); %// Cast back to uint8
```

This code will work if the image you are reading in is **grayscale**.

---

## Bonus - For Colour Images

However, if you want to apply the above for colour images, I don't recommend you use the above approach.  The reason being is you will only see a difference **if** the minimum and maximum values for each colour plane are the same - 0 and 255 respectively.  What I would recommend you do is normalize **each colour plane** separately so that you'll push each colour plane to the range of `[0,1]`, not being bound to the minimum and maximum of just one colour plane.

As such, I would recommend you do something like this:

```
lim3 = double(lim3); %// Cast to double
normimg = uint8(zeros(size(lim3))); %// Allocate output image
for idx = 1 : 3
    chan = lim3(:,:,idx);
    minvalue = min(chan(:));
    maxvalue = max(chan(:));
    normimg(:,:,idx) = uint8((chan-minvalue)*255/(maxvalue-minvalue)); %// Cast back to uint8
end
```

The above code accesses each colour plane individually, normalizes the plane, then puts the result in the output image `normimg`.  I would recommend you use the above approach instead if you want to see any contrast differences for colour images.